# Chrome/Chromium Extensions Error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

When I start Chrome, I sometimes get a little `!` (exclamation mark) on the tools popup menu. When I open the menu, there is a new entry "Extensions Error". When I select it, it goes to `chrome://chrome/extensions/` but on that page, there is no indication which extension has/causes problems.

How can I find out what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

On top of the extensions page `chrome://chrome/extensions/`, there is a checkbox "developer mode". Select it and an explanation of the problem should appear in a red box next to the extension which causes the problem.