# Chrome Extension Error--Which One?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

The menu button on Chrome is orange. When I click on it, the menu states there is an extension error. If I click on the error notification, I'm taken to the list of extensions that I have installed.

Nowhere in that list does it note which extension is causing the error.

According to [this several-year-old post](https://superuser.com/questions/465074/chrome-chromium-extensions-error), if I turn on developer mode, there should be a red box around the extension causing the problem. However, when I turn on developer mode, there is no indication of any kind for any of the extensions.

How can I tell which extension is causing the problem?

Comment: Divide and conquer. Disable 1/2 the extensions. Does it still fail - Yes. Then it is in the other 1/2. etc. etc.

Comment: I was hoping there was a quicker method than the process of elimination, especially since this error is not constant. It takes some time after a new browser session is started for it to appear.

Comment: @Tim - Have you tried David's suggestion?

Comment: @Ramhound I figured it out. I don't remember if I used his suggestion or not because I also remember suddenly realizing what extension it had to be (although I don't recall now).